# Correlation between 1D spatial categorical variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, spatial

I have two sets of data, representing presence/absence variables which vary along an axis (N=1e6):

```
position, value
1, present
2, present
3, absent
4, absent
..
```

The data represent the presence or absence of nucleosomes at positions on a chromosome, from two separate experiments.  Each typical nucleosome will be 'present' for something of the order of 100 adjacent positions, with each pair of nucleosomes separated by an absence of a similar length, but with a large variance in these lengths over the whole chromosome.

What would be a good way to summarise the agreement, correlation, overlap between the two data sets?  Ideally I would like to express this in R.
I am interested in looking at the general level of agreement between my replicate samples, and at the overall similarity with other, non-replicate, samples.

The R SpatialPack package seems to offer some promise.  The codispersion coefficient seems to offer an approach to this, but I'm not sure how valid that would be with categorical data.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what these data sets represent and how they were obtained or observed?  That could give us useful clues about what might be meant by any of the terms "agreement," "correlation," or "overlap."

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to give some more explanation.